# React map function in return statement only displays last record even though a console.log of my state (user) shows 3 records. Any ideas?

Tags: reactjs

**OVERVIEW**

I was able to set up my backend with express.js and as a test I hardcoded three users. In Login.js, I executed a get request to retrieve the data from the backend and store it into React's useState method. I am trying to display all three records in the return function using the map function, however, the only record that is being displayed on the client side is "Jane". I ran a console.log of my state and it shows all three records in the state.

```
**Console.log**

[{id: 1, name: "Sharif"}]

[{id: 2, name: "Mike"}] 

[{id: 3, name: "Jane"}]
```

**LOGIN.JS**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Login(req, res) {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/users')
            .then(function (response) {
                response.data.map(user => setUsers([user]));
            });
    }, []);

    console.log(users)
    return (
        <ul>
            {users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

**SERVER.JS**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {

    const users = [
        {id: 1, name: "Matt"},
        {id: 2, name: "Mike"},
        {id: 3, name: "Jane"},
    ]
  res.json(users)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the state setter `setUsers` multiple times with single value, which causes 3 renders. Instead you should just set the state to the result of the call (which you later correctly map over):

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/users')
        .then(function (response) {
            setUsers(response.data);
        });
}, []);
```